# Unable to handle NaN in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a variable, which, when I print it, shows up as mostly containing NaN. It is of dtype object. However, when I run the isnull function, it returns "FALSE" everywhere. I am wondering why the NaN values are not encoded as missing, and if there is any way of converting them to missing values that are treated properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NaN` are strings

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=['Not NaN', 'NaN', np.nan]))
print(df)

         A
0  Not NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
```

What's missing

```
print(df.isnull())

       A
0  False
1  False
2   True
```

The strings are not missing, the `np.nan` are.

You can `mask` the strings with

```
df.A.mask(df.A.eq('NaN')).isnull()

0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like another option is     df.replace('NaN', np.nan)

Answer (score -1):

Building on from piRSquared, a possible method to treating NaN values (if applicable to your problem) is to convert the NaN inputs to the median of the column.

df = df.fillna(df.mean())